# How do I find most recent (identical) document with findOne in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find a document in Mongoose by using findOne ( not find ), and I want to get the most recent document even though they may have identical fields.

For example, these are the documents in Mongoose:

```
// Let's say this one was created a week ago in Mongoose
{
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 27,
  industry: "finance"
}

// This one was created this morning
{
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 27,
  industry: "healthcare"
}
```

So I need to do a query along the lines of this:

```
const client = await Client.findOne({name: "John Smith"});

console.log(client);

/* 
result: 
{
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 27,
  industry: "finance"
} 

expected: 
{
  name: "John Smith",
  age: 27,
  industry: "healthcare"
}
*/
```

So when I `Client.findOne` by name, I'm expecting the most recent document. However `Client.findOne` seems to just return the old one.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the argument as an Object `sort: { 'created_at' : -1 }` changing -1 to 1 will fetch the oldest record
So your new query will look like

```
const client = Client.findOne({name: "John Smith"}).sort({created_at: -1});
```

Comment: I did it with something similar to your suggestion. Like so:
 
`const client = await Client.findOne({ name: "John Smith" }, null, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } } );`

**For future readers, for me, createdAt worked over created_at.**